# How to get speed of a train without using GPS

Tags: magnetic-fields, acceleration, gyroscopes

How can I measure instantaneous speed of a train  in which I am travelling without using GPS/location services?

The train can start underground or can start from ground level (where GPS is available) and then get underground in the subsequent stations.

The sensors which are present in iPhone are:

> Proximity sensor
>
> Ambient light sensor
>
> Accelerometer
>
> Magnetometer
>
> Gyroscopic sensor

and a Camera.

Can I use any of these or combinations of these to find the instantaneous speed of a train ?

I just want to know whether it is possible and if so, then please give me right direction to proceed further.

Comment: There is nothing in your phone that can do what you have in mind all by itself. The camera could do it, if there were useful markers on the tunnel walls or if the tracks had a constant and known distance between rails.

Comment: Are there mile/kilometer markers along the track? Or anything at fixed intervals? If so, you can use the stopwatch in your phone to determine the time and take distance over time. GPS would have to do the same thing, but can do it over shorter intervals. Either method would have to calculate your speed over some interval, though, and won't provide an instantaneous speed.

Answer (score 2):

In principle you can use the accelerometer in your iPhone as an [inertial navigation system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertial_navigation_system). If you know your initial velocity $\mathbf v_0$ and your iPhone tells you the acceleration as a function of time $\mathbf a(t)$ then your velocity at any time $t$ will be given by:

$$ \mathbf v(t) = \int_0^t \mathbf a(t')dt' $$

Sadly the reality is that the accelerometer in an iPhone is nowhere near accurate enough for this to be a useful technique.